# Sorts on relationships with Spaties QueryBuilder

Tags: laravel, sorting, query-builder

Having the following QueryBuilder statement how can I define sorts on related models columns?

```
$members = QueryBuilder::for(Member::class)
    ->allowedIncludes('user.name', 'association', 'affiliate')
    ->with('user')
    ->allowedFilters([
        AllowedFilter::exact('association.id'),
        AllowedFilter::partial('zip'),
        AllowedFilter::exact('specialisations.id')
    ])
    ->allowedSorts(['user.name', 'zip'])
    ->where('published', 1);
```

In this case the model Member is related to User and I want sort by User models name. Declaring the sort case `allowedSorts(['user.name'])` would not work.

Than I implemented the Sort interface to create a custom sorting on relationship as it follows

```
    $members = QueryBuilder::for(Member::class)
        ->with('user')
        ->allowedIncludes(['user', 'association', 'affiliate'])
        ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::exact('association.id'),
            AllowedFilter::partial('zip'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('specialisations.id')
        ])
        ->allowedSorts(
            AllowedSort::custom("user.name", new SortByRelation()),
            'zip'
        )
        ->where('published', 1);
```

the custom sort looks as it follows

```
public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
{
    [$relationName, $columnName] = explode(".", $property);

    $relation = $query->getRelation($relationName);

    $subQuery = $relation
        ->getQuery()
        ->select($columnName)
        ->whereColumn($relation->getQualifiedForeignKeyName(), $relation->getQualifiedOwnerKeyName());

    $query->orderBy($subQuery, $descending ? "desc" : "asc");
}
```

which is working on one sorted column but if I sort both of, just one theme will get the right sorting.

`sort=zip,user.name` is not working properly

Comment: I don't know about this package, but typically if you want to sort by a relationship, you need to actually `->join()` it. `->with()` performs a separate query instead of any kind of join clause, so your attempted `'user.name'` sort won't work. Does this package have any documentation for how to perform a `->join()`? (I see `->with()` is used, so it might just be as simple as `->join('users', 'members.user_id', 'users.id')`, then `allowedSort(['users.name', 'zip'])`)

Comment: Thanks for Feedback, as per documentation https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/features/sorting seems like there is an interface to declare custom sorts. I will try to implement

Comment: Sweet! So inside of that `_invoke()` method, the `Builder $query` can definitely accept a `join()` clause, then `->orderBy('users.name')` would work. Just have to watch for ambiguous columns, etc. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for an example of how to perform this sort using a custom sort, here you go.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomSorts;

use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Sorts\Sort;

class RepairOrderCustomerSort implements Sort
{
    public function __invoke($query, bool $descending, string $property)
    {
        // Join the customer relationship and sort results
        $query->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'repair_orders.customer_id')
            ->orderBy('customers.last_name', $descending ? 'desc' : 'asc')
            ->orderBy('customers.first_name', $descending ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    }
}
```

```php
// RepairOrderController.php

$repairOrders = QueryBuilder::for(RepairOrder::class)
    ->allowedSorts([
        AllowedSort::custom('customer', new RepairOrderCustomerSort()),
    ]);
```